# Extending Cells of the UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

[image: A Quick drawing of what I want]

I am looking at making a table view section that extends another section like the image.  Although this is purely aesthetic if you know of an easy way of doing this I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You different section can have different background image and different frames for the subviews.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LOC_ID"];
        [cell autorelease];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(indexPath.section == 0 && [self tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 == indexPath.section){
            //put background image for last row in section 0
        } else {
            //backgroundimaes for all other cells in section0
        } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
            //configure section 1 ibackgroundimages
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

setting background of an cell

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg.png" ]autorelease];  
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_selected_bg.png"];
```

Comment: So just create an image that looks like that and put it in the cell, I like that

Answer (score 1):

Nice diagram. If you are trying to create a UITableView with sections that have different widths, that is not possible. You will have to use two separate UITableViews with different widths, and put one below the other. Or just set up some UITableViewCells manually and don't use a UITableView at all.

Comment: How do u use UITableViewCells without a UITableView?

Comment: I didn't see that before but XCode has no problems with adding a UITableViewCell where there is no UITableView